# Javascript date +5 won't increment the month

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following code that does not want to properly add 5 days to a date.  here is the code:

```
// Grab previous session date so we can add 5 days and get new minDate
var currdate = new Date();
var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
var info = '';
var minDateBase = document.getElementById("class" + prevSession +  "_date").value;
var maxDateBase = document.getElementById("class1_date").value;
var minDateBits = minDateBase.split('-');
var maxDateBits = maxDateBase.split('-');
// Example Date working date 08-27-2012
// Example Date Not working date 09-03-2012
var minDate = new Date(minDateBits[2],minDateBits[0],minDateBits[1]);
var maxDate = new Date(maxDateBits[2],maxDateBits[0],maxDateBits[1]);
info = 'Selected Session Date: ' + minDate + '.' + "\n";
info = info + 'Class 1 date         : ' + maxDate + '.' + "\n";
var newMinDate = new Date();
var newMaxDate = new Date();
newMinDate.setUTCDate(minDate.getUTCDate() + 5);
newMaxDate.setUTCDate(maxDate.getUTCDate() + 42);
info = info + 'New Min. Date        : ' + newMinDate + '.' + "\n";
info = info + 'New Max Date         : ' + newMaxDate + '.' + "\n";
var maxDateDiff = newMaxDate.getTime() - currdate.getTime();
var minDateDiff = newMinDate.getTime() - currdate.getTime();
minDateDiff = Math.ceil(minDateDiff/one_day);
maxDateDiff = Math.ceil(maxDateDiff/one_day);
info = info + 'Min. Date Diff       : ' + minDateDiff + '.' + "\n";
info = info + 'Max  Date Diff       : ' + maxDateDiff + '.' + "\n";
alert (info);
```

Here is the output from the working "info" alert at the end:

> Selected Session Date: Mon Aug 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time).
>   Class 1 date         : Mon Aug 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time).
>   New Min. Date        : Sat Aug 25 2012 09:13:19 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time).
>   New Max Date         : Mon Oct 01 2012 09:13:19 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time).
>   Min. Date Diff       : 13. 
>   Max  Date Diff       : 50.

and here is the output from the non working "info" at the end ..

> Selected Session Date: Mon Sep 03 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time).
>   Class 1 date         : Mon Sep 03 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time).
>   New Min. Date        : Wed Aug 08 2012 09:15:09 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time).
>   New Max Date         : Fri Sep 14 2012 09:15:09 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time).
>   Min. Date Diff       : -4.
>   Max  Date Diff       : 33.

Any ideas why the "min Date" is keeping the same month value resulting in a time difference of -4?

Thanks,

Silver Tiger

** UPDATE **

My last idea seems to have addressed the issue,  updated the following code to reflect:

```
var minDate = new Date(minDateBits[2],parseFloat(minDateBits[0]) - 1,minDateBits[1]);
var maxDate = new Date(maxDateBits[2],parseFloat(maxDateBits[0]) - 1,maxDateBits[1]);
info = 'Selected Session Date: ' + minDate + '.' + "\n";
info = info + 'Class 1 date         : ' + maxDate + '.' + "\n";

var newMinDate = new Date();
var newMaxDate = new Date();

newMinDate.setTime(minDate.getTime() + (5 * one_day));
newMaxDate.setTime(maxDate.getTime() + (42 * one_day));
```

I will keep testing but it has worked on the first few tries...

Comment: looks like the quote line bleed into each other .. but the fact that they dates aren't adding up right is the issue.  both of the "max dates" should be 6 weeks after the calss1 date (which for this samples is indeed the selected date as well), and the min date should be +5 days from the "prevSession" date.

Comment: [`setUTCDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCDate) only sets the *day of the month* - `newMinDate` and `newMaxDate` are initialized with today's date, and that month information is not copied from your `minDate`/`maxDate`.

Comment: well that's something I didnt see coming .. is there a method that will include and modify the Month information appropriately?

Comment: Well, `getMonth`/`setMonth` should work, I guess.

Comment: Try `newMinDate = new Date(+minDate)` - this will convert `minDate` to milliseconds and create a new Date object with the same milliseconds value.

Comment: so creating a blank date (newMinDate) and populating it with minDate +5 ... why the +minDate? it seems to nearly double the error rate as the new minDateDiff becomes 51 instead..

Comment: on the getMonth and setMonth .. obviously i would need to error check if the +5 will take me into the next month ... would it be better to work in milliseconds until i have the final date and then convert it to a readable date after .. avoiding months and days altogether?

Comment: Working in milliseconds only works in ideal days, where daylight savings and leap seconds don't exist. I only used milliseconds as the fastest way to clone a full Date, for date math you definitely should use the real months and days.

Comment: darn ... so that "solution" I found is still buggy? ... guess I'll keep researching.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given a weekday and the day of the month it occurs, can I get its ordinal position in constant time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423801/given-a-weekday-and-the-day-of-the-month-it-occurs-can-i-get-its-ordinal-positi)

Comment: it wasn't a duplicate posted by myself, and I did not see the other post when searching, hence my post for help.